# Como crear consulta SQL con GROUP BY dinámico

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, transact-sql

Estoy intentado hacer una consulta a una tabla que tiene muchas columnas. Lo que necesito es poder consultar los datos agrupados por una de las columnas,  el resto que se agreguen dinámicamente, y así evitar escribir todas las columnas en el group by.

Hasta el momento tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT columna1, columna2, SUBSTRING(columna2, 1,1) as columna3 
FROM table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(columna2, 1,1)
```

Comment: En cuál base de datos, mysql o sqlserver. Por favor, usa sólo las etiquetas que correspondan a tu pregunta. Lo otro, "que se moldeen" qué significa?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: SQL, en resumen que me agrupe por una sola columna y no nombrando todas las columnas

Comment: Si es SQL Server se podría hacer un SP para realizar el group by dinámico.

Comment: Por favor edita y limita las etiquetas a aquella tecnología directamente usada (sea mysql o sql server), por cierto mysqli no aplica pues es una clase de PHP para conectarte a MySQL

Comment: tu respuesta no ayuda a mucho que digamos.

Comment: Si tienes dos registros que en la columna2 tienen A1 y A2, al agrupar tendrás un registro con la columna de grupo `A`, ¿Qué mostrar para columna2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer un SP para generar el group by dinámico, consultando el nombre de las columnas a la tabla INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS y concatenar los nombres en una variable, y así construir la query que será tu consulta final. Esto es útil cuando tenemos muchas columnas.

```
CREATE TABLE Pais (id int identity, columna1 varchar(50),columna2 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO Pais (columna1,columna2) values ('Guatemala','G1') , ('El Salvador','S2') , ('Nicaragua','N1'), ('Nicaragua','N2'), ('Nicaragua','N3') ,('Costa Rica','CR1')

DECLARE @ValoresGroup VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Pais' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))

DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ValoresGroup = ' columna3,' + @ValoresGroup

SET @QUERY =' 
SELECT DISTINCT columna1, columna3 FROM (
SELECT id, columna1, columna2, SUBSTRING(columna2, 1,1) as columna3 
FROM Pais
) T
GROUP BY ' + @ValoresGroup

EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pariendo de tu codigo

Comment: ?? no entendí tu comentario

Comment: partiendo de tu codigo me resulta util tu informacion, sin embargo me imprime todos los datos.

Comment: Reemplaza "SELECT * FROM" por  "SELECT DISTINCT columna1, columna3 "

Comment: he modificado la respuesta, se agrego el: SELECT DISTINCT columna1, columna3

Comment: además, se agrego tres registros nuevos: ('Nicaragua','N1'), ('Nicaragua','N2'), ('Nicaragua','N3')  para ilustrar la agrupación de los datos.

Comment: pero porque al momento de ejecutarlo no me imprime nada, solo el mensaje Commands completed successfully.

Comment: genial, me funciono perfectamente

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudarte bro. he modificado el título de tu pregunta para entender mejor lo que necesitábamos hacer. saludos

Comment: agradecido mucho hermano, se le aprecia.